# Enviar Imagen desde Excel a WhatsApp

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para poder enviar mensajes de WhatsApp con contactos de una base de datos desde Excel solo que me gustaria cargar las imagenes que tengo desde mi ordenador ya que actualmente solo copio pego una imagen en un hoja de excel especifica y de ahi ya lo envio cuando lo necesite, como podria hacer lo de cargar las imagenes desde el ordenador? Estoy trabajando con Macros en Excel con Visual Basic, Gracias de antemano

```
 Sub envioMensaje() 
    
    Dim Rango As Range
    Dim x
    Dim Mensaje As String
    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Inabilitar la pantalla
    
    
    For Each Rango In Hoja2.Range("Contactos[Cliente]") 'Nombre de la tabla y columna
    
   Mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & "57" & Rango.Offset(0, 6).Value & "&text=" & _
"Hola " & Rango.Value & " le escribimos desde ABC para informarle que al día de hoy tenemos una factura pendiente por pagar " & Rango.Offset(0, 1).Value & " del día " & Rango.Offset(0, 2).Value & " con un saldo de " & Rango.Offset(0, 5).Value & ", agradecemos enviarnos el comprobante de pago para cruzar el saldo. Muchas Gracias.", " ", "%20") 'indicativo + número + texto, utilizamos  VBA.Replace para reemplazar los espacios por %20 porque para whatsapp el espacio es %20


    
    
    
    x = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", Mensaje, &O0, &O0, SW_NORMAL)  'Para obtener el mensaje
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
    
    
    
    ''' para la imagen
    Hoja4.Select
    'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 4")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Copy
    Selection.Copy
    Call SendKeys("^v", True)
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04") 'Para esperar 4 segundos la ejecucion'
    
    
    
    Call SendKeys("~", True)  'El caracter ~ es para presionar enter y enviar el mensaje
    
    Call SendKeys("~", True) 'El caracter ~ es para presionar enter y enviar el mensaje
    
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04") 'Para esperar 4 segundos la ejecucion
    
    
    Call SendKeys("~", True)  'El caracter ~ es para presionar enter y enviar el mensaje
    
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  'Vaciar de nuevo la memoria
    
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate   'Volver la ventana
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04") 'Para esperar 2 segundos la ejecucion
    
    
    Next Rango
    
    
    Hoja1.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Habilitar la pantalla lo que hace
    
    MsgBox ("Mensaje con Exito"), vbInformation
    
    End Sub
```